# Firefox-Addon Dialog-like in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, firefox, dialog

Does anybody know how to make a dialog that looks a bit like the firefox-addon dialog. especially the list/gridview style...

I'm using WinForms with C#

[alt text http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/1781/21010307.jpg](http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/1781/21010307.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

create a custom UserControl with all needed controls on it (caption-label, info-label, picture, buttons, ...). Add some mouse and key-events.
For the "listview" inherit a new class from tableLayoutPanel. Add some methods to manage the UserControls (add, remove, focus).... and your done.

Ok, perhaps it could take a while. :-)